# Regex expression to match any non-digit except (- and .)

Tags: node.js, regex, google-apps-script

I am extracting some URL text from a wireless sensor using a GET command, but the data comes through with more info than I need and I will be putting it on a spreadsheet and into a chart so I need just the number (including any "-" or ".").

I am using

> /\D/g

to match any non-digit globally and then replacing it with nothing. A crude way of doing it but it works when there is no "-" or "."

My goal is to include those symbols (- and .) in the output so I need to exclude them from the regex match.

Currently what I have is...

```
var temp = UrlFetchApp.fetch("URL"); //Output is {"temperature": -62.01}
var tempNum = temp.getContentText().replace(/\D/g,"");
```

Input: {"temperature": -62.01}

Regex match

Replace match with blank ("")

Output goal: -62.01

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agree with JSON.parse, but just in case you still wanted to use RegEx...

```
var temp = UrlFetchApp.fetch("URL"); //Output is {"temperature": -62.01}
var regExp = new RegExp("{\"temperature\": (-?[\d.]*)}");
var temperature = regExp.exec(temp.getContextText())[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
replace(/[^\d\.-]/g,"");
```

Replace everything that's

- `^` Not a
- `\d` digit
- `\.` literal `.` or
- `-` literal `-`

But the output looks like json. If so, parsing is the right way to go:

```
var temp = UrlFetchApp.fetch("URL"); //Output is {"temperature": -62.01}
var tempNum = JSON.parse(temp.getContentText())["temperature"]; //-62.01
```